# urllib does not handle # character properly

Tags: python, urllib

I have my url that looks like as follows:

```
http://me:me1234#@localhost:8080/
```

When I run urlparse on this url, instead of the netlocpath returning **me:me1234#@localhost:8080** it only returns **me:me1234**.

```
from six.moves.urllib import parse
o=parse.urlparse('http://me:me1234#@localhost:8080/')
print o
```

ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='me:me1234', path='', params='', query='', fragment='@localhost:8080/')

Any idea how why it is failing to parse #? I think this is a pretty standard url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). You [need to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Reserved) encode it first:

```
from six.moves.urllib import parse
o=parse.urlparse('http://me:me1234%23@localhost:8080/')
print o
```

This should work for your needs.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a function to find and encode fragments like this? I may have a url that does not need encoding (without any characters such as #). I tried using parse.quote with no luck.

Comment: The fragment is not part of the netloc, so the parser is doing the right thing. If you think it isn't, why not just call `replace('#','%23')` on the url instead of quoting everything?